# Logic app how to get a file uploaded in microsoft forms

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-forms

I have a microsoft form where I attach a file (an excel) and I want to get this file and parse the content in Logic App. When I get the file, I receive an array like this:

```
{
  "name":"FileName.xlsx",
  "link":"https://xxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxx/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=xxxx",
  "id":"the Id",
  "type":null,
  "size":10310,
  "referenceId":"the reference Id",
  "driveId":"the drive Id",
  "status":1,
  "uploadSessionUrl":null
}
```

I don't know if I can get from this link the document or if there is another way to get the excel content uploaded in the microsoft form. Please, help me!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and here it is.

Steps:

[image]

Now the specifications:

[image]

[image: Parse JSON schema]

```
{
"items": {
    "properties": {
        "driveId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "link": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "referenceId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "size": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "status": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "type": {},
        "uploadSessionUrl": {}
    },
    "required": [
        "name",
        "link",
        "id",
        "type",
        "size",
        "referenceId",
        "driveId",
        "status",
        "uploadSessionUrl"
    ],
    "type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
```

}

[image]

**That gives you an output JSON with the excel table data**.
I hope it helps! Regards!

Answer (score 0):

***Reproduced the same issue and it's working fine, follow the below steps to get the content of uploaded file***

*An overview of the complete azure logic apps procedure*
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***In `SharePoint` you can go and check your files in the list you have created.***

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer but I cound't do it well :( Instead off, I found another solution wich I will publish in another answer.